# Unzipping gradle to install on macosx - Need GNU Compatible unzip

Tags: macos, installation, gzip, gradle

So that I can compile and test my code using gradle, I am trying to install gradle.

I want to unpack the Gradle distribution which comes packaged as a ZIP. However, there is a warning that says Mac OS X users should get a GNU compatible unzipper.

See http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/installation.html

> "..need a GNU compatible tool to unzip Gradle...some zip front ends for Mac OS X don't restore the file permissions properly."

Where can I get a GNU compatible tool to unzip Gradle?

I recall using gzip (gunzip to unzip) on other systems which is a gnu thing. My MacOSX has gzip / gunzip on it.

So, I tried the following:

```
gunzip gradle-1.4-bin.zip
```

It gave me this error:

```
gradle-1.4-bin.zip: unknown suffix -- ignored
```

I have followed several google posts and tried several different things. Listing those attempts would probably not serve at this point.

What does a person do to properly un-zip gradle on the Mac OS X so the file permissions are correct?

Comment: Either using Archive Utility (what you normally get when double-clicking a ZIP file) or the bundled `unzip`, the permissions were correctly restored on OS X 10.8.  I think this may be referencing older OS X versions where one or the other failed to restore permissions stored in ZIP files correctly.

Comment: Hey Will, who closed this as off topic, what Stack Exchange should I use in the future for software development tools that "automate the building, testing, publishing, deployment and more of software packages"? (from gradle.org)

Comment: Yeah, kinda weird that it was closed but not migrated somewhere more appropriate (probably Super User).  If I had this question I'd ask it in a more generally applicable way, something like "how do I get unzip on OS X to preserve permissions?"  chmod 777 is pretty overkill, anyway :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gunzip` is used for unzipping `.gz` files, typically created using the `gzip` command. `.zip` files should be unzipped using the `unzip` command, using an invocation like `unzip gradle-1.4-bin.zip`.

Answer (score 2):

Their note makes no sense.  There is no GNU unzip, nor anything about any unzipper that could be called "GNU compatible".  The zip format has nothing to do with GNU, and there are no GNU utilities that I'm aware of that process zip files.  Perhaps they are thinking that gzip, which is GNU, processes .zip files, which it doesn't (as you discovered).  gzip only works with .gz files, which are entirely different.  That page needs to be corrected.

As for the front ends, I don't know which ones they're referring to.  The command line unzip that comes with Mac OS X has always properly restored permissions and other attributes.

Comment: I couldn't agree more. :)

Comment: I have conversed with them about this, and they will be updating that page.